# Windows 8.1 In-App Search Control AND Search Pane (Search Charm)?

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1, windows-search

I'm trying to use the new 8.1 SearchBox Control in WinJS, but if I already have a Search Contract bound to my app for the Search Charm, I get an access denied error:
 `Can't hide this app in the search pane because the app has already accessed the search pane.`

Can I not use both the new Search Control and the Search Pane at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN documentation, no you can't:

> An app can't use both the search box (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SearchBox for Windows Store apps using C++, C#, or Visual Basic, WinJS.UI.SearchBox for Windows Store apps using JavaScript) and the SearchPane

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301949.aspx